# Moving HDD from Dell onto Alienware?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, dell-inspiron

I have 2 old laptops, both Windows. The dell is one I used often, but it's motherboard is completely fried. The alienware laptop still somewhat works. I want to get my old data from my dell, so I put its hard drive into the Alienware, but the Alienware is loading up to a black screen with a flashing underscore. I went into the bios boot settings, and it seems to identify the hard drive, I just need the computer to actual load it, regardless of damages it could cause to the Alienware, I just want the data.

Comment: get usb adaptor to plug hard drive into usb as an external drive rather like a giant usb stick.. they're not expensive.  But if it's really old and it's an IDE/ATA hard drive then be careful to plug it in correctly or the laptop will fry..

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do will usually be problematic.  Moving a hard drive with a Windows operating system from one computer to an entirely different machine (with different hardware architecture) typically won't allow you to boot into the operating system.

Is the old Dell hard drive SATA?  If so, it shouldn't be too difficult to find someone with a desktop that can temporarily connect your old drive as their secondary disk, allowing you to drag-and-drop your pertinent files to the desktop, copy them to an external USB drive, etc.

As an alternative, you can also find some good [USB-to-SATA adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VS4HDM) online that would allow you to connect your old Dell drive to another working computer as if it were an external USB device.